# JBOSS 7.1.1 : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Module "org.jgroups:main" from local module loader

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We are running JBoss 7.1.1 Final. We run Jgroup channel and send Messages over it. In org.jgroups.Message we set our custom objects which are present inside jars in lib of our ear.
our ear depends on module called pam "Dependencies: pam" and pam module add dependacy of jgroups

Now when we try to send and receive messages we are getting following exceptions

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 | 14:17:42,447 SEVERE [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK] (Incoming-8,PAM_Cluster_009bab72-bd07-4a97-993f-307f0161cd93,6ea3721c-4e05-4d4c-b0de-d0e17acdbaf0) couldn't deliver message [dst: <null>, src: ba1438dc-c17d-4dca-b30d-62bd4d755b3d (3 headers), size=859 bytes]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pam.automation.server.GlobalDBNotification from [Module "org.jgroups:main" from local module loader @6f991ccf (roots: C:\Jboss7\node1\standalone\..\modules)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.Message.getObject(Message.java:379) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at com.pam.automation.server.ClusterViewChangeListener.processMessagage(ClusterViewChangeListener.java:119) [clusterservices-snapshot.jar:4.2]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at com.pam.automation.server.ClusterViewChangeListener$1.receive(ClusterViewChangeListener.java:84) [clusterservices-snapshot.jar:4.2]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.JChannel.invokeCallback(JChannel.java:758) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:719) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1026) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:178) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:181) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:400) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:418) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:881) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:244) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST.up(UNICAST.java:332) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.handleMessage(NAKACK.java:730) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.up(NAKACK.java:559) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.BARRIER.up(BARRIER.java:126) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:140) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:273) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:282) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.up(MERGE2.java:205) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:355) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1174) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.handleMyMessage(TP.java:1722) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.run(TP.java:1699) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pam.automation.server.GlobalDBNotification from [Module "org.jgroups:main" from local module loader @6f991ccf (roots: C:\Jboss7\node1\standalone\..\modules)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:498) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at javax.management.Notification.readObject(Notification.java:370) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:991) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1866) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369) [rt.jar:1.7.0_01]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.util.Util.objectFromByteBuffer(Util.java:416) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           at org.jgroups.Message.getObject(Message.java:376) [jgroups-3.0.6.Final.jar:3.0.6.Final]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/04/22 14:17:42 |           ... 26 more
```

Currently to solve this problem we have added jgroup jar inside lib of our ear.
Is there any other way to solve this type of serialization problem?

Comment: Did you define the classes in jar as a dependency in modules configuration file?

Comment: where is com.pam.automation.server.GlobalDBNotification class?

Comment: its inside lib of my ear

Answer (score 0):

The `module.xml` file for the org/jgroups/main module is missing a dependency, in this case the module or .jar file which contains the `GlobalDBNotification` class. Add the missing dependency and the error will go away.

Comment: GlobalDBNotification class in lib folder of my ear.

Comment: GlobalDBNotification class in lib folder of my ear. I dont see any problem using JGroups until I set GlobalDBNotification as a object in org.jgroups.Message.

Comment: Adding that into the lib folder of your EAR violates JBoss 7 modular design principle. Modules can be used by any deployment, so internal dependencies of modules have to be defined and satisfied in the module itself, not in some deployed project. See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7#Installing_a_JDBC_driver_as_a_module on  how to configure a module for JBoss 7.